# Apache Commons Lang 2 vs 3

Tags: java, apache, jar, apache-commons

In my application I'm using apache commons Lang v.3.
A requried library give my a

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
```

Is there a build translation between commmon.lang to commons.lang3 or I have to add both lang libraries?

Comment: You might be including libraries that requrire the older/newer version

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can have both Lang2 and Lang3 in your classpath.  Due to incompatibility of Lang2 and Lang3, the package is intentionally changed from `com.apache.commons.lang` to `com.apache.commons.lang3` so that you can have both version in classpath without conflict