# NoSuchMethodError when running on Hadoop 2.9

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I had a project which currently runs on `Hadoop 2.7`.
I tried running it on `Hadoop 2.9` but its attempts are failing with following error:

```java
2019-03-05 14:56:06,672 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MRAppMaster metrics system started
2019-03-05 14:56:06,683 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Adding job token for job_1551420856137_58235 to jobTokenSecretManager
2019-03-05 14:56:06,689 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobSubmittedEvent.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$500(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:1010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$JobEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceStart(MRAppMaster.java:1242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1723)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1650)
2019-03-05 14:56:06,695 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobSubmittedEvent.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;)V
```

Same code is running on `Hadoop 2.7` but failing on `Hadoop 2.9`. I have searched for similar issues and tried fixing. But still its not working.

Comment: Please check your dependencies and be sure that you dont have same dependency 
with different versions

Comment: Which build tool are you using?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura maven

Comment: Could you show me your dependency:tree?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura https://gist.github.com/0x6773/334ae9b9d992c636557cbe1f570b35f2

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/2.9.0
You can check if all your dependencies are compatible with versions
As i find out you have commons-lang3 
But hadoop-yarn-client/2.9.0 needs 2.6

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura I believe that's not a problem. Both versions can be included without conflicts. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159089/3789604).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189509/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-0x6773).